# python-- a program to show the value held in certain coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, coordinates

im still new to programming, but a problem i am trying to sonve with my friend is about a table that is one hundred thousand in the x direction, and one hundred thousand in the y direction, with the origin at 1,1. the graph follows a pattern that looks like this:

```
| 7
| 4 8
| 2 5 9
| 1 3 6 10
```

what we came up with so far is this, but it isnt working optimally, and we would like help in optimizing it and making it work better. our code looks like this:

```
def solution(x,y):
    if ((x == 1) and (y == 1)):
        return 1
    mult = 1
    s = 0
    i = x-1
    while (i > 0):
        mult += .5
        i -= 1
    s += int(x * mult)
    increase = x
    for i in range(1,y-1):
        x += 1
        increase += x

    return s + increase

print(solution(5,10))
```

if it worked properly, it would have given the result 96 for the coordinate (5,10), and 9 for (3,2)
any help is appreciated, thank you dearly.

Comment: What is the solution supposed to do?

Comment: The current solution that you have is able to produce 96 for the coordinate (5,10), and 9 for (3,2). Is your question only about optimizing the current code?

Comment: @MoonCheesez the program is supposed to provide the id of the number in the cordinate location

Comment: @CooLio could you provide a minimal and complete example? I don't see a (5, 10) in your table above, neither do I see a 96 anywhere.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary yes please, we want to make sure it can run accuratley, and on occasion we would recieve errors for random coordinates, and in others, wed recieve the wrong answer. thank you for responding, it really means a lot

Comment: @MoonCheesez the table above was a smallsnippet of the full table, as it is supposed to be 100000 square units. a good full example of what the program is supposed to do is if we were to look for the value at 1,3, the program would respond with 4 ((1,1) is the origin)

Answer (score 0):

Following the same variable name that you have used

`mult` is effectively equal to 1 + (x-1) / 2

`s` is effectively equal to `mult * x`

increase can be thought as `x + x*(y-2) + sum_of_n(y-2)`

where `sum_of_n` function is the sum of n natural number.

This is the worked-out explanation for 2 input that you gave.

**Example1:**

```
For coordinate (3,2) 

mult is effectively  1 + (x-1) / 2  = 1 + (3-1)/2 = 2

s is mult * x = 2 * 3 = 6 

increase can be thought as x + x*(y-2) + sum_of_n(y-2) = 3 + 3*(2-2) + sum_of_n(0) = 3 + 0 + 0 = 3

so final answer is s + increase = 6 + 3 = 9
```

**Example2:**

```
For coordinate (5,10) 

mult is effectively  1 + (x-1) / 2 = 1 + (5-1)/2 = 3

s is mult * x = 3 * 5 = 15 

increase can be thought as x + x*(y-2) + sum_of_n(y-2) = 5 + 5*(10-2) + sum_of_n(8) = 5 + 40 + 36 = 81

so final answer is s + increase = 15 + 81 = 96
```

The code snippet which does this is

```
def solution(x,y):
    if ((x == 1) and (y == 1)):
        return 1
    if(y==1):
        return sum_of_n(x)
    s = 0
    mult = 1 + (x-1)/2  
    print("mult is " + str(mult)) 
    s += int(x * mult)
    increase =  x + x*(y-2) + sum_of_n(y-2)
    return s + increase

def sum_of_n(n):
    if n> 0:
        return (n*(n+1))/2
    else:
        return 0

print(solution(5,10))
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: do you mind telling me how to have it return as a string? turns out int is much more limited than i thought it was. thank you dearly by the way

Comment: You are welcome.  If the solution has helped you, you can accept the answer as the accepted solution. To answer your question, str(int_value) would produce the string equivalent. For example, str(12) would produce '12'.

Comment: just add str before every return value in the snippet. For example `return 1` would become `return str(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. As far as I know this is the fastest solution (because it calculates the solution directly without looping). If you look closely, the table is just a series of [arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). Hence, you can calculate the values directly:

Take a look at each row:

```
7

4 8
 +4
2 5 9
 +3+4
1 3 6 10
 +2+3+4
```

Notice that the starting increment increases by one for every increase in `y`, and the value then has a steady increase of `n`, `n+1`, `n+2`, ...:

```
+4
+3+4
+2+3+4
```

With that information we can easily calculate the value as so:

```
def sum_from(start, end):
    # This formula assumes that the common difference is 1
    n = end - start + 1
    return n * (start + end) / 2

def solution(x, y):
    # Calculate the first value on the left of the table
    y_start = 1 + sum_from(1, y-1)
    # Calculate the first increment
    x_sum_start = y + 1
    # Calculate the sum of all the increments
    x_increment = sum_from(x_sum_start, x+y-1)
    return y_start + x_increment
```